# Dificuldade em criar Threads

Tags: android, delphi, thread

Estou tentando criar uma Thread. Porém sou iniciante no assunto. Alguém pode apontar onde meu código está errado. Não está funcionando

```
Procedure TFormPrincipal.ButtonCompartilharProxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ButtonComp_Voltar.Enabled       := False;
  ButtonComp_SalvArq.Enabled      := False;
  ButtonComp_Agora.Enabled        := False;
  TabControlForm.TabIndex         := 4;
  ProgressBarComp.Min             := 1;
  ProgressBarComp.Max             := ListView_Pessoas_Lista.Items.Count ;
  LabelComp_TituloStatus.Text     := '...Aguarde...';
  LabelComp_StatusProgresso.Text  := '...Iniciando...';
  CDS.Close;
  CDS.CreateDataSet;
  CDS.Open;

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure ()
  var
    a :integer;
  begin
    a                               := 0;
    PessoasTable.First;
    while not PessoasTable.Eof do
      begin
      CDS.Insert;
      CDS.FieldByName('Nome').AsString      := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Nome').AsString;
      CDS.FieldByName('Apelido').AsString   := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Apelido').AsString;
      CDS.FieldByName('Endereco').AsString  := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Endereco').AsString;
      CDS.FieldByName('Cidade').AsString    := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Extra1').AsString;
      CDS.FieldByName('Data').AsString      := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Data').AsString;
      CDS.FieldByName('Data_Nascimento').AsString := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Data_Nascimento').AsString;
      CDS.FieldByName('Idade').AsString     := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Idade').AsString;
      CDS.FieldByName('Ocorrencia').AsString:= PessoasTable.FieldByName('Ocorrencia').AsString;
      CDS.FieldByName('Nome_Pai').AsString  := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Filiacao_pai').AsString;
      CDS.FieldByName('Nome_Mae').AsString  := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Filiacao_mae').AsString;
      CDS.FieldByName('Documento').AsString := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Documento').AsString;
        if FileExists(PessoasTable.FieldByName('Foto_Caminho').AsString) then
          begin
          ImagePreviewIncorp.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(PessoasTable.FieldByName('Foto_Caminho').AsString);
          CDS.FieldByName('Foto1').Assign(ImagePreviewIncorp.Bitmap);
          end;
      CDS.Post;
      a     := a+1;
      PessoasTable.next;
 //     Application.ProcessMessages;
      TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,      {Durante o Loop}
        procedure ()
          begin
            LabelComp_StatusProgresso.Text        := 'Incorporando Arquivo: '+PessoasTable.FieldByName('Foto_Caminho').AsString;
            ProgressBarComp.Value:=ListView_Pessoas_Lista.ItemIndex;
          end);
      end;

    TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
      procedure ()
      begin  {Final}
        if not DirectoryExists('mnt/sdcard/BancodeImagens/Enviar') then
          try
            ForceDirectories('mnt/sdcard/BancodeImagens/Enviar');
          except
          on e: exception do
            ShowMessage('Não foi possível criar o diretório mnt/sdcard/BancodeImagens/Enviar. Erro: '+
                         e.Message);
          end;
      LabelComp_StatusProgresso.Text  := '...Salvando Arquivo...';
      CDS.SaveToFile('mnt/sdcard/BancodeImagens/Enviar/'+GeraNumeroRegistro+'.XML');
      CDS.Close;
      LabelComp_TituloStatus.Text     := 'O Que Deseja Fazer Com O Arquivo?';
      LabelComp_StatusProgresso.Text  := '...Terminado...';
      ProgressBarComp.Value           := ProgressBarComp.Max;
      ButtonComp_Voltar.Enabled       := True;
      ButtonComp_SalvArq.Enabled      := True;
      ButtonComp_Agora.Enabled        := True;
      end);
  end).Start;

end;
```

Comment: "Não está funcionando" ? o que acontece? não compila? da erro de execução?

Comment: Se existe um DataSource ligado ao seu CDS, as operações que você realiza no corpo da _thread_ irão disparar atualizações em tela que irão comprometer a execução. Quando em uma _thread_, nenhuma operação que afete direta ou indiretamente a tela pode ficar de fora do   `Synchronize`.

Comment: Consegui resolver Com o Código abaixo, não sei porquê mas tive que transferir o código que fazia o carregamento de uma imagem em arquivo e gravava numa tabela SQlite para o Synchronize. 

Porém Surgiu outro problema: Quando deixo meu app rodando em segundo plano para utilizar outro app e volto para o meu app ele está travado.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver Com o Código abaixo, não sei porquê mas tive que transferir o código que fazia o carregamento de uma imagem do arquivo e gravava numa tabela SQlite para o Synchronize.

Porém Surgiu outro problema: Quando deixo meu app rodando em segundo plano para utilizar outro app e volto para o meu app ele está travado

```
var
  a, Qtde:integer;
begin
  with FormPrincipal do
  begin
  ButtonComp_Voltar.Enabled       := False;
  ButtonComp_SalvArq.Enabled      := False;
  ButtonComp_Agora.Enabled        := False;
  TabControlForm.TabIndex         := 4;
  ProgressBarComp.Min             := 0;
  ProgressBarComp.Max             := ListView_Pessoas_Lista.Items.Count ;
  LabelComp_TituloStatus.Text     := '...Aguarde...';
  LabelComp_StatusProgresso.Text  := '...Iniciando...';
  CDS.Close;
  CDS.CreateDataSet;
  CDS.Open;
 // PessoasTable.First;
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure ()
  var
    I: Integer;
    Total: Integer;
   begin
    Total := 1;
    while not PessoasTable.Eof do
      begin
        CDS.Insert;
        CDS.FieldByName('Nome').AsString      := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Nome').AsString;
        CDS.FieldByName('Apelido').AsString   := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Apelido').AsString;
        CDS.FieldByName('Endereco').AsString  := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Endereco').AsString;
        CDS.FieldByName('Cidade').AsString    := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Extra1').AsString;
        CDS.FieldByName('Data').AsString      := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Data').AsString;
        CDS.FieldByName('Data_Nascimento').AsString := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Data_Nascimento').AsString;
        CDS.FieldByName('Idade').AsString     := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Idade').AsString;
        CDS.FieldByName('Ocorrencia').AsString:= PessoasTable.FieldByName('Ocorrencia').AsString;
        CDS.FieldByName('Nome_Pai').AsString  := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Filiacao_pai').AsString;
        CDS.FieldByName('Nome_Mae').AsString  := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Filiacao_mae').AsString;
        CDS.FieldByName('Documento').AsString := PessoasTable.FieldByName('Documento').AsString;
        TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,      {Durante o Loop}
          procedure ()
          begin
             LabelComp_StatusProgresso.Text        := 'Total: '+Total.ToString+
                          ', Adicionando Registro: '+PessoasTable.FieldByName('Registro').AsString;
             ProgressBarComp.Value := ListView_Pessoas_Lista.ItemIndex;
             if FileExists(PessoasTable.FieldByName('Foto_Caminho').AsString) then
               CDS.FieldByName('Foto1').Assign(
                CarregaImagemArquivo(PessoasTable.FieldByName('Foto_Caminho').AsString)
                 );
          end);
        CDS.Post;
        Total := Total+1;
        PessoasTable.Next;
      end;

    TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
      procedure ()
      begin  {Final}
        ProgressBarComp.Max             := ProgressBarComp.Max;
        LabelComp_StatusProgresso.Text  := '...Salvando Arquivo...';
        CDS.SaveToFile('mnt/sdcard/BancodeImagens/Enviar/'+GeraNumeroRegistro+'.XML');
        LabelComp_StatusProgresso.Text  := 'Terminado';
        LabelComp_TituloStatus.Text     := 'O Que Deseja Fazer Com O Arquivo?';
        CDS.Close;
        ButtonComp_Voltar.Enabled       := True;
        ButtonComp_SalvArq.Enabled      := True;
        ButtonComp_Agora.Enabled        := True;
      end);
   end).Start;

    if not DirectoryExists('mnt/sdcard/BancodeImagens/Enviar') then
      try
        ForceDirectories('mnt/sdcard/BancodeImagens/Enviar');
      except
        on e: exception do
          ShowMessage('Não foi possível criar o diretório mnt/sdcard/BancodeImagens/Enviar. Erro: '+
                       e.Message);
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Porque o código acessa os componentes Visuais que estão na MainThread. Para acessar qualquer componente Visual ou não visual que foi criado na MainThread, você deve utilizar o Syncronize para que a MainThread pare de processar as mensagens evitando assim uma "race condition".

Comment: Você teria como me mostrar via código?. Desde já agradeço a ajuda e todos os esclarecimentos.

Comment: Você respondeu sua pergunta ou criou outra? Não entendi...

Comment: Eu respondí porém criei esta situação que relatei acima.